# c# How put comma after every digit of a long type number separating even and odds?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, split

C# I want to know How to place a comma after every digit of a long type number (input parameter) separating even and odds?

Example: InsertComma(12272358) should return "1,22,7,2,35,8"

Comment: Did you try a for loop, if and string concatenation?

Comment: To iterate trhought a long make it a string. it will be easier or make it an int[] using %10 and /10 operation

Comment: Given `% 10` is relatively slow, you may want to consider tweaking the answers provided to instead do subtraction (i.e. element minus the element before it) **then** `% 10` (since odd - odd = even, and even - even = even), rather than two separate `% 10` operations. Alternatively, keep track of the next elements `% 10` calculation and reuse it, rather than calculating it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
private static string InsertComma(long v)
{
        var strArray = v.ToString().ToArray();
        //compares current element to next one and insert separator if is needed
        //last element is ignored due to preventing index exeption
        var result = strArray.Take(strArray.Length-1)
        .Select((x, index) => ((x % 2) == (strArray[index+1]%2)) ? x.ToString() :x+ ",");
        return string.Join("", result)+strArray.Last() ;
}
```

Using For loop:

```
private static string InsertComma(long v)
{
        var result = "";
        var strArray = v.ToString().ToArray();
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < strArray.Length-1; i++)
        {
            result += strArray[i];
            //compares current element to next one and insert separator if is needed
            if ((strArray[i]%2) != (strArray[i + 1] % 2))
                result += ",";
        }
        return result + strArray[i];
}
```

Use:

```
Console.WriteLine(InsertComma(12272358));
```

Output:

```
1,22,7,2,35,8
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to enumerate thought a Int's digits is to make it a string.
Then for each element of this string we will lock it it's has the same reminder than the previous element in this case we need to concatenate them. Except for the first element as there is no previous.

```
var input = 54721704;
var str = input.ToString();

var result = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        result.Add(str[i].ToString());
        continue;
    }
    if (Char.GetNumericValue(str[i]) % 2 == Char.GetNumericValue(str[i - 1]) % 2)
    {
        result[result.Count() - 1] += str[i].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(str[i].ToString());
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

https://rextester.com/UML19116

You can improve this by avoiding unnecesseray access to the previous element casting and modulo computation by storing the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Covert to string and then loop.

```
string CovertNumber(int source) {
  var result = new StringBuilder();
  var src = source.ToString();
  var wasEven = false;
  for (var i =0; i < src.Length; i++) {
    var digit = int.Parse(src[i].ToString());
    var isEven = (digit % 2) == 0;
    if (i > 0 && isEven != wasEven) {
      result.Append(",");
    }
    result.Append(digit.ToString());
    wasEven = isEven;
 }
 return result.ToString();
}
```

This code will bomb on a negative number  so you will need to validate input or use Math.Abs to ignore the sign.